# How to get a flexbox to fill 100% of the height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a User interfact setup but the flexbox is not expanding all the way downwards. As we can see I am trying to get a 25% / 75% split between the sections vertically and I want the sections to take the rest of space downwards but it only goes as far as the lowest element in either of the sections.

I've tried height: 100% but that does not seem to work. Not sure what to do from here.

```css
#horizontalTake {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
}


#side {
    flex: 25%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 35px;
}


#main {

    flex: 75%;
    background-color: #e1e6ed;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
              <div id = 'horizontalTake'>
                    <div id = "container">
                        <div id = "side">
                            <center>
                                <h3> TestOne </h3>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div id = "main">
                            <center>
                               <h3> TestTwo </h3>
                            </center>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using 100% use 100vh this will take full height of the window and 
flex-direction: row; will set instead of row

```css
#horizontalTake {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

#side {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex: 25%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

#main {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex: 75%;
  background-color: #e1e6ed;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='horizontalTake'>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="side">
      <center>

        <h3> Day Overview </h3>
      </center>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <center>
        <h3> Test </h3>
      </center>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi sorry, I updated my code to show the code I meant to post. I think you got to my problem before I updated my code.

Comment: no prob. i guess my code is working for you. isn't it? if not please tell me where i have miss? i will fix that @WhatManHasMade

Comment: Im trying to get my sections to split horizontally so like | - | -----  | and take up the remaining height of the screen. If you look at my edited code in the problem statement, it will give you a better idea. Your code is splitting it vertically, but thats not your fault since that was my old code. Was hoping you could help me with my updated code. Thanks!

Comment: I have update the code. is that what you want?

Comment: my pleasure. please accept my answer as an accepted answer :)